# 3x2GB RAM plus 1x2GB, no triple channel?

Tags: memory, triple-channel

Currently my system has 3x2GB DDR3 RAM. I need to add 2 GB more. [This is](http://www.gigabyte.us/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3305#ov) my motherboard

and i use the white slots for triple channel. 
So, first question:
If i add one more RAM stick into a blue slot will the triple channel stop?

If yes 2) Will adding 3x2GB into the blue slots (all slots filled) keeps the triple channel working?

Comment: Yes it will stop, but honestly, the performance loss will be minimal.  If you are worried fill all slots

Comment: @Ramhound Does it matter which slot to use? (the first and second blue slot is under a huge cpu fan, and it's very difficult to disassemble it).

Comment: You should read the manual for your motherboard, any answer I generated, would be generated from reading your manual.  I am more willing to do that, but your particular question, can be answered by reading the manual to your motherboard so I won't do that.

Answer (score 0):

> If I add one more RAM stick into a blue slot will the triple channel stop?

I am not sure. In theory the first three DIMMs could be accesses in triply channel mode and the memory controller could use normal access for the fourth DIMM.

> Will adding 3x2GB into the blue slots (all slots filled) keeps the triple channel working?

Yes.  Both triplets of DIMMS will work in triple channel mode.